# How to display the integers from 1 to 20 using a while loop and the counter variable i without initializing i=0

Tags: c#

How do I Display the integers from 1 to 20 using a while loop and the counter variable i ,just by declaring it and not  initializing it in the beginning. One more condition is that I have to display only five integers per line.I have to do it in c#
Sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


             int i;
            while(i==20)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                else
                    Console.Write(i);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot really using `int` variable *without* first initializing it, it will give you *compiler error*.

As for the way to write 5 items in one line, you have multiple ways to do it. One way is like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 20) {
            Console.Write(++i);
            Console.Write(++i);
            Console.Write(++i);
            Console.Write(++i);
            Console.WriteLine(++i);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The idea is simply to use `Console.Write` when you do not need to write a line. You can replace the above lines with `if-else` block also, as what you have done in your code.